# "A * doesn't a good * make"

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm curious about a certain sentence construct that I've seen in different contexts. I'm talking about sentences in the following style:

```
A * doesn't a * make.
```

(<kbd>*</kbd> being a wildcard). For example:

```
A good camera doesn't a good photographer make.
```

A [google search for that specific sentence construct](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22A%20*%20doesn%27t%20a%20good%20*%20make%22) yields several results. However, the placement of the verb at the end of the sentence seems to be a grammatical error to me.

Is this construct grammatically correct? Is it archaic? Is it derived from a famous quote? Or is it just plain wrong?

Comment: I just want to replace your google search with [this search](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=%22doesn%27t+a+good+*+make%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=3ME5V82NGYm60ATLu7nAAw#safe=off&q=%22A+*+doesn%27t+a+good+*+make%22), which is more specific

Comment: It's quite a common construct, if not something you hear every day. The word "good" isn't necessarily required.

Comment: @nnnnnn I edited the question accordingly. zyurnaidi, I changed the google search as well

Comment: A lightsaber doesn't a Jedi make - Yoda.

Comment: @Glorfindel a good jedi or a bad jedi? 

Comment: @AlanCarmack Only a sith in absolutes deals

Comment: FYI the general idea of a pattern where you fill in the blanks to make a new saying that alludes to an old one is called a "snowclone": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone

Comment: Damn, I was hoping this would be about the A* algorithm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is grammatically correct. The most common usage is probably the proverb, "[one swallow does not a summer make](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make)".

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/why-is-xxxx-doth-not-a-yyyy-make-considered-valid-english) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25508/is-employing-hyperbaton-correct-in-english) are some explanations of this word order. In short, it's an [hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton) used to emphasize "make", and it is considered archaic (or poetic).

Comment: +1, but I don't see how it can be considered archaic if the construction is still in use today.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, afaik, if it won't be in use today, it would be considered obsolete, not archaic. Archaisms just sound old-fashioned outside of specific context

Comment: @AlanCarmack: A single, idiomatic use does not a non-archaic word make.

Comment: @AlanCarmack The construction is valid, but no one uses it these days except in this context, so it sounds very archaic.

Comment: Hello! People  [the Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22A%20*%20doesn%27t%20a%20good%20*%20make%22)  included in the question  shows multiple contemporary uses  of this construction.......

Comment: *Bartlett's Familiar Quotations*, 18th Edition (2012), page 78:5, attributes "One swallow does not make a summer" to Aristotle in *Nicomachean Ethics* I, *7.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack If *methinks* is not archaic (based on its [frequency of usage on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=methinks&src=typd&lang=en)), you may wish to inform [Merriam-Webster of their error](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/methinks). `:)` Whether a word is archaic depends in part on whether it registers tonally as archaic. A word being archaic doesn't mean that it's not used or understood (as mentioned above, that's *obsolete*).

Comment: Related proverb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barba_non_facit_philosophum “A beard does not constitute a philosopher,” attributed to "the Athenian aristocrat, ex-Roman consul and man of letters Herodes Atticus."

Comment: Aristotle wrote in Greek, which (afaik) had/has a more flexible word order than English. Translators into English had/have the choice of retaining the original word order or rearranging it to the English of their time, which is why 'does not a summer make' and 'does not make a summer' are both found. As well as being poetic, SOV can sound (mock-)philosophical. (I found the original quotation in Greek, but Google Translate couldn't cope with Attic Greek and returned gibberish.) (BTW, Google Ngrams shows 'does not make a summer' is far more common.)

Comment: The swallow/summer proverb may be the oldest and most well known use of this sentence construction, but I don't think it is archaic because it is still used quite often for non swallow/summer purposes. (It's not something *everybody* says, of course, but I know a few people who do say it. Including me.)

Answer (score 4):

The sentence that jumps into my mind is

> One swallow does not a summer make.

You can read more about the sentence, including historical uses at the [Wikitionary Page](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make) for it. The alternative sentence with *... does not make a summer* sounds lackluster in comparison.

So,   no it's not ungrammatical or outdated, and your latest Google search brings up several examples.

Comment: but is the swallow African or European?